# How to increment value of textbox each time user clicks the button in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Hi I have this button which displays number 1 on a textbox on a different page.
I have been trying to increment the textbox value each time the user clicks on the button. I have set the transferred value as 1 already on the first page.
At the moment the textbox just appears as 2 because it gets the value of the transferred data and increments to 2 on a click of the button.

Here is the code for the button which transfers the data to the next page and displays it in the textbox.

I want the textbox to increment each time the user clicks the button.

Page 1

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App app = Application.Current as App; // declared the variable "storeValue"in app.cs as an integer.

    app.storeValue = 1; //setting the value as 1 
}
```

Page 2- Code which displays the variable to the textbox

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    App app = Application.Current as App;
    app.storeValue++;
    int totalq = int.Parse(textBox.Text) + app.storeValue;
    textBox.Text = totalq.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Um don't you want `app.storeValue++` in the `button_Click` event, and `app.storeValue = 1` somewhere else? (probably your `OnNavigatedTo`). Right now every time someone clicks the button, it sets `storeValue` to 1, instead of *incrementing* the value by 1.

Comment: Every time the user clicks the button it should increment the text value on the second page. @EldarDordzhiev

Comment: Wait, you meant the textbox's value increase 2 each time?

Comment: No it doesn't increment it stays as 2. I explained why it stays at 2 in my question. @DRKblade

Comment: @samuel It doesn't increment when you click the button, it gets incremented when you navigate to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Page 1

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   App app = Application.Current as App; // declared the variable "storeValue"in app.cs as an integer.

   app.storeValue++;
}
```

Page 2- Code which displays the variable to the textbox

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  App app = Application.Current as App;
  //app.storeValue++;
  int totalq = int.Parse(textBox.Text) + app.storeValue;
  textBox.Text = totalq.ToString();
}
```